# How to move a file from inside my Docker container via a script without a password

Tags: docker, scp, bitbucket-pipelines, docker-container

I am trying to move a file from inside my Docker container to my local machine. I have tried using scp but every time it asks for a password which I cannot input as I would like this to be done via a script. As it will be done at the end of my pipeline.

As I am using Bitbucket pipelines the containers are not persistent so I cannot create ssh keys from within the containers. I tried to use the public key from my local machine and put it in a authorized_keys file within the container and try to scp from within but this didn't work.

Am I missing something or is there another way to move the file remotely from within the container without using a password?

Any questions or help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean to SCP a file from the container running the bitbucket pipeline step to a remote SSH server? Or from a `docker run <image> scp <xxx>` instruction?

Comment: In the repo settings you can set up SSH keys, you create a key pair and paste the public key in your authorized_keys

Comment: @N1ngu Kind of. I have Bitbucket Runners on my local machine which run the pipelines. I want to move a file from one of these containers to the same local machine in a certain folder.